stylelint not automatically fixing content as expected
I am trying to use the stylelint tool to automatically fix some css.
I read through their docs and am using the CLI tool instead of with a traditional setup.
I installed the tool using npm
npm install -g stylelint stylelint-config-standard-scss

Then I created a config based on their docs
stylelint.config.mjs
/** @type {import('stylelint').Config} */
export default {
    extends: "stylelint-config-standard-scss",
    rules: {
        "block-no-empty": true,
    }
};

I then created a sample css file 01.css
.selector {
    display: block;
    invalid: property;
}

Based on the default rules there is only one error in this css file invalid: property
I run the following in my cli
npx stylelint --config stylelint.config.mjs --fix 01.css > 01-fixed.css

The output is correct in showing the error:
 npx stylelint --config stylelint.config.mjs --fix 01.css > 01-fixed.css                                                                                                                                                    13:00:16

01.css
  4:5  ✖  Unexpected unknown property "invalid"  property-no-unknown

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

When inspecting my 01-fixed.css file it is empty.
Why is this file empty? Am I missing some configuration?
I have looked at other questions on this topic but found no help.
eg: How do I set stylelint to fix errors automatically?
I have also looked into the github issues but found nothing that explains this issue.
Any help is appreciated, I assume I have missed some configuration.
